# Plotly : Use two sliders together in a barplot

Tags: r, plotly

Im trying to create a barplot that contain two sliders, but I can't make them work.
My desired output is, through the use of two sliders, change the values of `p1` and `p2` and display a barplot that shows two bars per `Ratio` and per `Power` (4 in total, or 2 if doing a subplot per `Ratio`). For example, select p1 = 0.45 and p2 = 0.2, and it will display 4 bars (or also create to different plots for both `Ratio` and then use `subplot()` ), each bar with `n` height and for every `Ratio : Power` combination.

Reproducible data:

```
p1 = seq(0.05,1,0.05)
p2 = seq(0, 0.95,0.05)
df = expand.grid(p1 = p1,p2 = p2)
df = df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df_1)), times = 4), ] %>% 
mutate(ID = 1:1600, 
Ratio = rep(c("1:1","2:1"), each = 400*2), 
Power = rep(c("80%", "90%"), each = 400, times = 2), 
n = rgamma(1600,shape = 10))
```

Plot code:

```
p1_range = data.frame(p1)
p2_range = data.frame(p2)
colnames(p1_range) <- "x"
colnames(p2_range) <- "x"

all_p1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(p1_range[,])) { 
  all_p1[[i]] <- list(method = "relayout",
                       args = list(list(p1 = round(p1_range$x[i],2))),
                       label = round(p1_range$x[i],2))
}

all_p2 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(p2_range[,])) { 
  all_p2[[i]] <- list(method = "relayout",
                      args = list(list(p2 = round(p2_range$x[i],2))),
                      label = round(p2_range$x[i],2))
}

plot_1 = plot_ly(df[df$Ratio == "2:1",],type = "bar", x = ~Power, y = ~n, color = ~Power, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E')
              )%>% layout(sliders = list(
                list(
                  active = 1, 
                  currentvalue = list(prefix = "Longitude: "), 
                  pad = list(t = 0), 
                  steps = all_p1),
                list(
                  active = 1, 
                  currentvalue = list(prefix = "Latitude: "), 
                  pad = list(t = 0), 
                  steps = all_p2)))
```

This is what I get:

[image: Actual output]

As you see, sliders are overlapped and also don't work when i choose a value. Hopefully I explained myself enough to make me understandable.